# using ([0-9]+) after (.*) in htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my code

```
RewriteRule ^film-(.*)-p([0-9]+)$ cat.php?n=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

but the problem is the script makes all what is after (.*) like a variable and ([0-9]+)
  = nothing.  Please help, I need to finish this project.

Comment: What is the requested url?

Comment: film-bandes-annonces-p2
and it's should go to
cat.php?n=bandes-annonces&page=2
but it goes to
cat.php?n=bandes-announces-p2

Comment: From this: `RewriteRule ^film-(.*)-p([0-9]+)$ /cat.php?n=$1&page=$2 [R]` I get redirected to `/cat.php?n=bandes-annonces&page=2`. Is that not what you're going for? If so, and it's not working.. do you have other rewrite rules before this?

Comment: `^film-(.*?)-p([0-9]+)$` should reduce greediness

Comment: Well, I checked your rule and it works as expected for me

Comment: sorry but all the solutions do not work

Answer (score 0):

How about using “([^-]*)“ instead of “(.*)“？

^film-([^-]*)-(p[0-9]+)$

Answer (score 0):

the probleme is solved

my code was

RewriteRule ^film-(.*)$ cat.php?n=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^film-([^-]*)-p([0-9]+)$ cat.php?n=$1&page=$2 [L]

i changed to

RewriteRule ^film-([^-]*)-p([0-9]+)$ cat.php?n=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^film-(.*)$ cat.php?n=$1 [L]

and now it's works thanks